# Scala 2.13.1 error when compiling en "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/TraversableOnce"

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, scala-compiler, scala-2.13

I'm switching from Scala 2.12 to 2.13.1.
When I compile the project in sbt I get this error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/TraversableOnce
[error] java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error] java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
...
```

Of course this error won't happen in Scala 2.12.

I've been reading that "Traversable and TraversableOnce are replaced with Iterable and IterableOnce, respectively" (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html), so it seems related. However I can't find in the code where Traversable/TraversableOnce is being used, so I can replace it with Iterable/IterableOnce.

Any help?
Thank you!

PS: 
- build.properties: sbt.version=1.3.3
- build.sbt: scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

This is the complete error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/TraversableOnce
[error] java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error] java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.JavaReflectionRuntimes$JavaReflectionResolvers.resolveJavaReflectionRuntime(JavaReflectionRuntimes.scala:28)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.JavaReflectionRuntimes$JavaReflectionResolvers.resolveJavaReflectionRuntime$(JavaReflectionRuntimes.scala:27)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes$MacroRuntimeResolver.resolveJavaReflectionRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:61)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes$MacroRuntimeResolver.resolveRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:74)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$standardMacroRuntime$3(MacroRuntimes.scala:47)
[error] scala.collection.mutable.MapOps.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:148)
[error] scala.collection.mutable.MapOps.getOrElseUpdate$(Map.scala:145)
[error] scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:268)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:47)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:40)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.standardMacroRuntime(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:472)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:469)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:410)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:469)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:469)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.pluginsMacroRuntime(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:34)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:34)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.macroRuntime(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.$anonfun$expand$1(Macros.scala:563)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global.withInfoLevel(Global.scala:226)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.expand(Macros.scala:557)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.apply(Macros.scala:544)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand(Macros.scala:719)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand$(Macros.scala:717)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.standardMacroExpand(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$10.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:456)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$10.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:453)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:410)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:453)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:453)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.pluginsMacroExpand(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand(Macros.scala:708)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand$(Macros.scala:701)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.macroExpand(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.vanillaAdapt$1(Typers.scala:1212)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1277)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1250)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1270)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.typedImplicit1(Implicits.scala:866)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.typedImplicit0(Implicits.scala:803)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Implicits$ImplicitSearch$$typedImplicit(Implicits.scala:622)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch$ImplicitComputation.rankImplicits(Implicits.scala:1213)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch$ImplicitComputation.findBest(Implicits.scala:1248)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.searchImplicit(Implicits.scala:1305)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.bestImplicit(Implicits.scala:1730)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits.inferImplicit1(Implicits.scala:112)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits.inferImplicit(Implicits.scala:91)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits.inferImplicit$(Implicits.scala:88)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.inferImplicit(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits.inferImplicitFor(Implicits.scala:46)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits.inferImplicitFor$(Implicits.scala:45)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$5.inferImplicitFor(Global.scala:483)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.applyImplicitArgs(Typers.scala:270)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$adapt$1(Typers.scala:879)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adaptToImplicitMethod$1(Typers.scala:499)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1273)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5900)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5950)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3394)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3394)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedBlock(Typers.scala:2536)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedOutsidePatternMode$1(Typers.scala:5815)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5850)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5886)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:5948)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5793)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5886)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5950)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3394)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3394)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:2049)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1879)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5794)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5886)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5950)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3394)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3394)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5494)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5797)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5886)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.apply(Analyzer.scala:115)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:452)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.run(Analyzer.scala:104)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1506)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1490)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1614)
[error] xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:153)
[error] xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:125)
[error] xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:39)
[error] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:248)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:122)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:95)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
[error] scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:1761)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:1734)
[error] scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error] sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error] sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error] sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error] sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error] sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error] sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you manage to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Unfortunately nope, I had this error and others that I couldn't solve so for now I decided to stay in 2.12 ...

Comment: I found that I was bundling in one 2.12 library, was hidden among many of the dependencies in build.sbt. Once I got rid of that, it started to work

Comment: Ok, thank you Peter, I will take a look, may be this is my problem too. Thank you!!